# How to debug in github CI?

Tags: github-actions, pull-request, apache-iotdb, iotdb

It's very weired that my code passes all UT/IT in my laptop, but it encounters errors in github CI.
Would you mind helping to take up some methods to debug in github CI? Or to make code runs in local as same as github?

It's a project about timeseries database, Apache-IoTDB. The error looks like a trivial logical error among ordinary code. Hope it may help diagnose the bug. Thank you very much !

Comment: There is nothing weird about your code passing the tests locally but failing to do so on a CI server. Sometimes a simple case misconfigured line endings can cause a build to fail on a Unix machine whereas the same code passes on a Windows machine.

Comment: That's a really complex CI pipeline! You might find this helpful: [Downloading logs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-workflow-run-logs#downloading-logs). By downloading the logs you can more carefully examine the output of each action *step* because the log gets truncated in the browser if it's too long. From what I was able to discern, you have some test errors in what seems to be multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question solved directly by merging master(the branch my pull request forward to) again.

The point is, github CI (actions) may be running on the code which is AUTO-MERGED when the pull-request accepted.

So if your code passes all tests locally but failed in CI with different result from your local debugging, try merge the branch which PR forward may solve the problem.

Hope this may hepl you and thanks guys under this question.

Answer (score 5):

[act](https://github.com/nektos/act) is a local runner for GitHub Actions workflows and should run nearly identically to the real thing.

Alternatively, the [debugging-with-ssh](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-ssh) action uses [upterm](https://upterm.dev/) to open an SSH listener within a container to get a shell on a running workflow within GitHub Actions itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this tools now